# Can't run ios test in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mobile

I could run my app on simulator, but can't run any tests. I think they could run only on simulator, but XCode does not show me any button with simulator. How to run test while ios development process?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9mix.png)

[test targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyZHS.png)

[run targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n4CK.png)

Comment: You should not "Run" test target, you should "Test" the test target (or go to Test Navigator tab, and run tests from there). Also seems the Base SDK for your test target is set to Mac, while it should be iOS (go to Build Settings for your Test Target and check)

Comment: Please post (at least) the error message as text. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should "Test" the target instead of "Run" it.
[image]

Comment: It does not work. 

"Cannot test target “Tests iOS” on “My Mac”: My Mac’s macOS 12.0.1 doesn’t match Tests iOS’s macOS 12.1 deployment target. "

Comment: I think you need to add a few more details to your question then.

Answer (score -1):

I would say Command U (Run Test). You might also need to select UnitTest from targets.

Comment: It does not work. 
Cannot test target “Tests iOS” on “My Mac”: My Mac’s macOS 12.0.1 doesn’t match Tests iOS’s macOS 12.1 deployment target.

Comment: I believe you would need to give more information about this issue.